# align watermark with php to top left corner instead bottom right

Tags: php

I tried many ways to change coordinates of watermark image to top left corner but I can't understand which of variables defines top,left,right and bottom corner.

I hope you can help

```
 //Source folder where all images are placed
 $source="source";

 //Destination folder where all images with watermark will be copied
 $destination="destination";

 //Creating an image object of watermark image
 $watermark=imagecreatefrompng("watermark.png");

 //Margin of watermark from right and bottom of the main image
 $margin_right=10;
 $margin_bottom=10;

 //Height ($sy) and Width ($sx) of watermark image
 $sx=imagesx($watermark);
 $sy=imagesy($watermark);

 //Get list of images in source folder
 $images=array_diff(scandir($source), array('..', '.'));

 foreach($images as $image){
    //Create image object of main image
    $img=imagecreatefromjpeg($source.'/'.$image);

    //Copying watermark image into the main image
    imagecopy($img, $watermark, imagesx($img) - $sx - $margin_right, imagesy($img) - $sy - $margin_bottom, 0, 0, $sx, $sy);

    //Saving the merged image into the destination folder
    imagejpeg($img, $destination.'/'.$image,100);

    //Destroying the main image object
    imagedestroy($img);
}

 //Destroying watermark image object
 imagedestroy($watermark);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's in your code !

```
//Margin of watermark from right and bottom of the main image
 $margin_right=10;
 $margin_bottom=10;
```

I'm not sure how your script work, but you may add :

```
$margin_left=10;
$margin_top=10;
```

And remove :

```
$margin_right=10;
$margin_bottom=10;
```

*It's not really related to PHP ! It looks like CSS configuration !*

Comment: Not really. Look code a little better and you will see

Comment: I don't see anything about that !

Comment: Do't you see that $margin-right=10; $margin-bottom=10; are only variables? If i change that to margin-leftand margin-top it will throw  an error since imagecopy requires variables with name $margin-right and $margin-bottom?